# How to show images uploaded by a specific user in Phocagallery - Joomla?

Tags: php, joomla, components

I am using phocagallery to show images/pictures on my site and i am looking for a way to show a link to the user which leads the visiting user to see the albums created by a specific user. Currently I have found way to show the current user's photos etc. but i need a way to see some specific user's pictures. is it possible? If yes then how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the developer answered my query on his forum:

http://www.phoca.cz/forum/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=7538&p=32554